# pandas to_sql() error with empty dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I am working with pandas to update tables in an sqlite database.
The dataframe that I use can be sometimes empty. When I use to_sql() with this dataframe, I have a sqlite3.OperationalError. This happens when the parameter index is set to False.

simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 

con = sqlite3.connect("C:\\an_user_dir\\a_base.sqlite")

# error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
pd.DataFrame().to_sql('temp', con, if_exists="replace", index=False)

# no error
pd.DataFrame().to_sql('temp', con, if_exists="replace")
```

So, the error is : `sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error`

I started digging on this error, and found that it is because of the name of the table: "temp".
Somewhere in pandas or sqlite, the table name becomes `"temp (\n)(\n)"`, hence the error.

Is this a normal behaviour, or an actual bug? Could someone explain this to me?

Thank you !

Comment: well I was expecting to get just a single table (just as with the second example).
What really confuses me is the existence of the double "(\n)" in the table name. Why would that happen?

Comment: `temp` is a [reserved word in sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Comment: oh i didn't think about it ! but in that case, why would it work in one case and not the other ? I'll try changing the name of the table.